# Outlook Addin Dialog Box Browser

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm having trouble receiving a response from my Outlook add-in dialog box because I am unable to authenticate myself with it. This activity also happens with Internet Explorer which brought up the question, does Outlook Desktop use IE when displaying add-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your OS/Platform version. You can find a more detailed explanation in the article, [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins).